# How to convert dynamic table rows to columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-tables

I want to convert the below table into my expected output format. Here the input is dynamic. But my code should be generic to handle dynamic input tables

Input 1:

| key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Id | 1 |
| Name | AAAA |
| Id | 2 |
| Name | BBBB |

Output 1:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA |
| 2 | BBBB |

Input 2:

| key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Id | 1 |
| Name | AAAA |
| Dept | IT |
| Id | 2 |
| Name | BBBB |
| Dept | Admin |

Output 2:

| Id | Name | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA | IT |
| 2 | BBBB | Admin |

Not able to find any results

Comment: That' not a "dynamic" input table. That's a well know *bad design*, known as the Entity-Attribute-Value *anti*pattern. There are a *lot* of answers that show how to fix it. It's a bad design because instead of offering "dynamic" columns, it eliminates them, making it impossible to query the data, constraint or check the values, or even use meaningful indexes. It offers *no benefits* over the XML, JSON, array or object support offered by all databases.

Comment: As for fixing this, there are a *lot* of answers and blogs that show how you can convert this to a proper table using PIVOT or `GROUP BY` on the primary key, extracting the known "attributes" into proper columns. In the relational model, the table defines the *relations* between its columns. You can't have a relation when you don't even know what things it works on. Foreign Key Constraints are that - constraints, not relations. If you have extra columns that are rarely queried by themselves, you can store them as a "bag" of attributes in a JSON or XML field.

Comment: Input 1:


| jsonb                    | 
| -------------------------| 
| {"ID":"1", "Name":"AAAA"}|
| {"ID":"2", "Name":"BBBB"}|


Output 1:

| Id | Name   |
| ---| -------|
| 1  | AAAA   |
| 2  | BBBB   |


Input 2:

| jsonb                                    | 
| -----------------------------------------| 
| {"ID":"1", "Name":"AAAA", "Dept":"Admin"}|
| {"ID":"2", "Name":"BBBB", "Dept":"IT"}   |


Output 2:

| Id | Name   | Dept |
| ---| -------| ---- |
| 1  | AAAA   | IT   |
| 2  | BBBB   | Admin|

Comment: Is it possible if I am getting my input as jsonb set